# can we use consul to give site specific endpoint URL?

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

Basic and Naive question, I saw a demo on youtube how consul server and agent can work together to deliver a web service hosted at port 80 based on its availbilty. i.e. from which server is up , it will make that service availble. However for scenario I am asking if we can specifically redirect user to an endpoint of similar web service based on the location where the user is requesting from ?
if its is possible what confuguration for consul would it take to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consul uses a network tomography system to compute network coordinates for nodes in the cluster. Inside a data center this can be used in combination with [Prepared Queries](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/query#near) (in addition to [other methods](https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/coordinates#network-coordinates-in-consul)) to discover service instances near a given agent in the data center.

For traffic from external users, you'll want to a use a DNS global traffic manager like [NS1](https://ns1.com/) or F5's BIG-IP DNS to direct end-users to the closest data center. Once inside the data center, you can utilize Consul to route the connection to the nearest service instance.

See this blog post from NS1 about their integration with Consul, and ability route traffic based on service location. https://ns1.com/blog/hashicorp-and-ns1-automating-application-networking-for-microservices

Comment: Thank you greatly appreciated.